# Accessing json object inside javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the "name" values in Javascript.

```
$scope.networkIds =[
  {
    "name": "ghdth",
    "value": []
  },
  {
    "name": "dddd",
    "value": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Nrgyr",
    "value": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Ntehyt",
    "value": []
  }
];
```

Currently I am using following code:

```
for(var i=0;i<=$scope.networkIds.length;i++){         
     $log.info(angular.toJson(networkIDsArray[i].name));
  }
```

But I am getting error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `$scope.networkIds` != `networkIDsArray`

Comment: Use `$scope.networkIds` instead of a never-declared `networkIDsArray`...
so: `console.log($scope.networkIDsArray[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your

```
<= $scope.networkIds.length
```

you will have to use

```
< $scope.networkIds.length
```

because an array with x entries has the valid indexes from
0 to x - 1

Comment: u are genius . Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes , i am trying to . But we need to wait for some time to mark answer as accepted.To mark your answer as accepted i will have to wait for 2 min :)

Answer (score -1):

***Assuming*** you're actually doing `$scope.networkIDsArray[i].name` or can otherwise explain the discrepancy between your variable names, then you probably just have an off-by-one error here:

```
for (var i=0; i <= $scope.networkIds.length; i++)         
                ^^
```

You want `<` instead of `<=`, otherwise you're doing one iteration too many and the last iteration gives you this error.